# how to mock server endpoint in RestAssured

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

i am doing  API testing of a bank application (kind of mobile banking) where client gets connection  through phone as a sms code.There is an endpoint where u enter received code to get access to  other functionalities of the app. And it is not good practice everytime to update manually the code in my automation coding. And, it is not possible to make code static for testing purpose.
Is there any way how to handle or what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/) rule

Official website includes sample like following:

```
stubFor(post("/my/resource")
    .withHeader("Content-Type", containing("xml"))
    .willReturn(ok()
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
        .withBody("<response>SUCCESS</response>")));
```